# Как правильно добавлять данные из цикла fetch в массив. Нет возможности обратится к индексу и длине массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, fetch, hook

[[image: Такой массив получается в array и в итоге в ships, нет возможности обратится к индексу и длине массива][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzqb2.png)

```
const [ ships, setShips ] = useState()

useEffect(()=> {
    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(film => {
            const starships = film.starships //Ссылки на данные конкретных объектов
            const array = []
            starships.forEach(ship => {
                fetch(ship)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => { 
                        array[array.length] = data
                    })
            })
            console.log(array)
            setShips(array) 
        })          
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае я бы поменял серверный API, чтоб можно было запрашивать подробности starships за раз. Т. к. иначе получается много лишних http запросов.

`array[array.length] = data` работает не очень, т. к. реакт не узнает, что стейт поменялся.

Если вызывать `set*` после каждого мелкого запроса, будет наоборот лишний рендеринг.

Можно решить на клиенте через `Promise.all`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2").then(res => res.json())
            .then(film => {
                const starships = film.starships //Ссылки на данные конкретных объектов
                return Promise.all(starships.map(ship => fetch(ship).then(res => res.json())))
            }).then(data=>setShips(data))         
    }, [])
```

Comment: еще момент, fetch не считает http ответы не-2хх ошибкой; стоит это учитывать в реальном коде; и вообще показывать что-то красивое пользователю, если что-то пошло не так

Comment: Благодарю за и ответ и его разъяснение

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку ваш пример кода не самодостаточный, мне трудно проверить решение, так что могу только предположить. Проблема в том, что `starships.forEach()` обычно не подходит для работы с асинхронным кодом: в вашем варианте он запустит все запросы синхронно и не будет дожидаться их окончания, поэтому дальнейший код будет иметь дело с пустым массивом. Возможно, самый простой способ — использовать цикл в async/await функции, если вам подходит, что запросы будут отсылаться последовательно. Если вам нужно параллельное выполнение запросов с ожиданием конечного результата, тогда стоит рассмотреть `Promise.all()`, как вам посоветовали в другом ответе.

```js
fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(async (film) => {
    const starships = film.starships
    const array = []
    for (const ship of starships) {
      const res = await fetch(ship)
      const data = await res.json()
      array.push(data)
    }
    console.log(array)
    setShips(array)
  })
```

Comment: добавил параллельное решение

Comment: хороший пример `async`; но параллельное решение, вероятно, будет иметь меньшие задержки

Comment: Да, но оно больше нагрузит сервер: если массив большой, будет отправлено одновременно много запросов.

Comment: Так же благодарю за альтернативный подход и его разъяснение!